# Wordpress app behind ELB jQuery not defined

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

I have configured an ELB on AWS and defined path routing rules in the following way:

www.example.com -> navigates to a React app

www.example.com/blog -> Navigate to a wordpress app

The problem I have is that when I navigate to my wordpress app I get lots of error because it tries to fetch all content from www.example.com, whereas that content is on my wordpress server.

How can I configure my wordpress app to fetch images from the server where it is actually hosted, instead of fetching them from www.example.com?

Comment: I think you need to check the wordpress config on AWS and see if you can change the 'site_url' to point to 'www.example.com/blog'.  I've no idea about ELB or AWS but wordpress does allow you to configure the site url.

Comment: See Update WordPress Configuration via https://blog.lawrencemcdaniel.com/wordpress-aws-elb-ssl/